# how to serialize an array/list/mat filled with complex number

Tags: python, json, serialization

I want to serialize an ndarray/list filled with complex number, the example code is here:

```
a = [None]
a[0] =  0.006863076166054825+0j
a
[(0.006863076166054825+0j)]
>>> b = json.dumps(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: (0.006863076166054825+0j) is not JSON serializable
```

so how to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json.dumps(a)` will fail, because the function can not handle the complex number when it tries to interpret it. The only possibility to pass the value is as string:

```
a = [1]
a[0] = "0.006863076166054825+0j"
b = json.dumps(a)
print b
```

which outputs

```
["0.006863076166054825+0j"]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok  let me make it clear

I found another way to do it.
use the module pickle

eg:

```
fp = open("1.txt","w")
a = [1,2,3]
pickle.dump(a,fp,0)
fp.close()
```

to load is the same:

```
fp = open("1.txt")
a = pickle.load(fp)
print a
fp.close()
```

it can serialize any object as long as it can find the class

Answer (score 0):

I needed this problem's solution too. I have written this code and it works for the task that I need, but when I ran it through checks it does not complete all the tasks. Still, one can use it.

```
# turn complex to str
def replace_complex( inp):
    """Replace complex numbers with strings of 
       complex number + __ in the beginning.

    Parameters:
    ------------
    inp:       input dictionary.
    """

    try:
        if isinstance(inp, complex):
            return "__" + str(inp)
        elif isinstance(inp, list):
            for each in range(len(inp)):
                inp[ each] = replace_complex( inp[ each])
            return inp
        elif isinstance(inp, dict):
            for key,val in inp.items():
                inp[key] = replace_complex( val)
                return inp
        else:
            return inp # nothing found - better than no checks
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return ""
```