# PLOTLY: TypeError: Object of type 'complex' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, plotly, linear-algebra

```
# Now plot
tot = sum(eig_vals)
var_exp = [(i / tot)*100 for i in sorted(eig_vals, reverse=True)]
cum_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp)

trace1 = Bar(
    x=['PC %s' %i for i in range(1,5)],
    y=var_exp,
    showlegend=False)

trace2 = Scatter(
    x=['PC %s' %i for i in range(1,5)], 
    y=cum_var_exp,
    name='cumulative explained variance')

data = Data([trace1, trace2])

layout=Layout(
    yaxis=YAxis(title='Explained variance in percent'),
    title='Explained variance by different principal components')

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#display(data)

py.iplot(fig)
```

Gives me this error: 
    ---> 25 py.iplot(fig)
    TypeError: Object of type 'complex' is not JSON serializable

Any help on how to fix?

Comment: what does eig_vals look like? numpy array? can you show some of your data please.

Comment: Some of your eigenvalues are complex numbers so having the form ```a+bj```. You will not be able to plot this on a standard x-y plane or serialize it normally. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473953/how-to-serialize-an-array-list-mat-filled-with-complex-number) question talks about serializing complex numbers. Consider using ```np.real()``` to plot just the real parts for now.

Comment: Solution: use eigh instead of eig to get the eigenvalues and vectors.